# Error : Callback function is not a function

Tags: node.js

I have server file and db.js file (connecting to db). In the exports.connect I use function with 'done' parameter (It is callback function). But 'done()' isn't work and wrote error 'done is not a function' in console.
What can I do?
server.js:

```
let db = require("./db"); 
let MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
let ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

app.listen(3164, function() {
  console.log("API app started");
});
db.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017",{useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true},err => {
  if (err) {
     console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

db.js:

```
let MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
let state = {
  db: null
};

exports.connect = function(url, done) {
  if (state.db) {
    return done();
  }
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    state.db = db;
    done();
  });
};
exports.get = function() {
  return state.db;
};
```

Console log: TypeError: done is not a function

at /home/bukrole/db.project/db.js:16:5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared function `connect(url, done)` which takes only 2 parameters, and in file `server.js` you are calling it with 3(the second one is an object). You have to modify your function declaration to `function connect(url, params, done)`

Answer (score 1):

In `db.js` Change

```
exports.connect = function(url, done) {
```

TO

```
exports.connect = function(url, options, done) {
```

Because you are calling the function as `db.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017",{useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true},err => {` by three params.

**NOTE**

But you are not using the options in db.js file better you avoid that while calling itself